# Ajax - Load data work fine in Firefox but not work in IE, Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, handsontable

I try to make async: false, type="POST" and dataType="html", but it still not work in Chrome and IE.

I declare  in my index jsp, but its not show up when use chrome and IE. var containerEmail = $("#dataEmailObj"); and handsontableEmail = containerEmail.data('handsontable');

And use alert(res.data) in function(res), it still show the data i want. The problem is sometime it not show up on screen, sometime it show

Here is codes:

```
handsontableEmail = containerEmail.data('handsontable');
    $.ajax({
        url : "load-EmailConfig",
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type : 'GET',
        success : function(res) {
            handsontableEmail.loadData(res.data);
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("Could_not_load_data");
        }
    });
```

Comment: not work means what?

Comment: I declare <div id="dataEmailObj"></div> in my index jsp, but its not show up when use chrome and IE.
    var containerEmail = $("#dataEmailObj"); and handsontableEmail = containerEmail.data('handsontable');

Comment: Any errors in the chrome console?

Comment: No, i use alert(res.data) in function(res), it still show the data i want. The problem is sometime it not show up on screen, sometime it show.